# Avoid auto-hyperlink generation with knitr, markdown

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

`knitr` automatically generates links when knitting .Rmd to .html. Very often that's useful, but just now it's not what I want.

Suppose you have this .Rmd file:

```
---
title: "Doc title"
output: html_document
---

I don't want this@to-be-a-link.com, but it comes out that way. 

If you wrap it in an R expression  `r "this@is-still-a-link.com"`.

Is there some kind of CSS trick I can avail myself of if I wanted <style='nolink'>www.something.com</style> not to be a link?
```

Knitting like this:

```
library(knitr)
knit2html('that_file.Rmd', 'that_file.html')
```

results in all those things being links.

[image]

Is there an easy way to generally keep the auto-link generation, but disable it selectively in particular lines? Thanks for any thoughts.

Edit: i guess I should have actually tried the solution below before accepting. This in the .Rmd

```
I don't want this <!-- breaklink -->@to-be-a-link.com
```

...doesnt actually parse to an HTML comment, because the -- gets changed to an em dash (by knitr? pandoc?) and then I get:

[image]

Comment: Do you just not want it to show as a link or remove the link entirely? Also, why would you use an R expression and not just bare backticks in the second attempt?

Comment: This seems hacky, but you could "break" the link with something like `<!-- -->` inserted as part of the URL....

Comment: Didn't want the bare backticks version, because I wanted plain text output. Didn't expect the R expression would necessarily work, but was just showing what I tried / threw at the wall.

Comment: I think this might be a pandoc question, really.... The answer I've posted seems to work for HTML and DOCX, but not for PDF.

Answer (score 8):

Two options that I see are (1) using bare backticks, or (2) "breaking" the link by using an empty HTML comment.

Example:

```
---
title: "Doc title"
output: html_document
---

I don't want this<!-- -->@to-be-a-link.com, but it comes out that way. 

If you wrap it in an R expression `this@is-still-a-link.com`.

Is there some kind of CSS trick I can avail myself of if I wanted 
<style='nolink'>http<!-- -->://www.something.com</style> not to 
be a link?
```

Becomes:

[image]

Comment: @arvi1000, Well, it's a comment--so you can make it verbose, like `this<!-- breaklink -->@to-be-a-link.com` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this party, however there's another way to accomplish this using [html entities](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_c.asp).

Using an entity rather than the normal charater-mark will essentially escape whatever and when rendered will not become a hyperlink.

For example, if I wanted a url to be in plaintext(meaning i dont want it to look like `code` , which for most cases would work just fine), but i had a usecase where I wanted part of the url to be bold, so:

**In my `.Rmd` file:**

```
Hyperlinked  
: https://sub-domain-**env**.domain.com/path/to/collection
Non-Hyperlinked  
: https&#58;//sub-domain-**env**.domain.com/path/to/collection
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most localized way to do this is to "backslash-escape" the *at* sign:

```markdown
I don't want this\@to-be-a-link.com, and now it isn't.
```

This also works with weblinks:

```
Not a link: https\://posit.co
```

The autolink feature can also be completely disabled by turning off the `autolink_bare_uris` extension:

```markdown
---
title: "Doc title"
output:
  html_document:
    md_extensions: -autolink_bare_uris
---

I don't want this@to-be-a-link.com, and now it isn't.
```

URLs must then be wrapped in angular brackets to get a link: `<https://posit.co>`.

See also the "HTML document" section in the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html).